# How to Split a column in dataframe based on a value?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Have a df with one column :

```
   0
Test  : bat
Test2 : ball
Test3 : Moon
```

How to split this into another column. Based on (:)

expected output :

```
0     |   1
Test     bat
Test2    ball
Test3    Moon
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) method with `expand=True` to split strings around given separator/delimiter. When `expand=True`, `split` will return DataFrame/MultiIndex expanding dimensionality.

```
>>> df
     0
0   val1:val2
1   val3:val4

>>> df["0"].str.split(':', expand=True)

    0     1
0   val1  val2
1   val3  val4
```